# How to add another date to a date selected from popup calendar in Qt C++

Tags: c++, qt, datetime

I am doing a library management system project in QT C++. in handling burrowing of books i use qdatetimeedit to select the current date. I want to assign the return date by adding 2 weeks to the current date and it should be displayed in a line edit once i select the current date from popup calendar. I don't have an idea to carry this out. Please help. Thank you in advance

Comment: ui->dtetimeCurrnt->setCalendarPopup(true); QDate current = ui->dtetimeCurrnt->date();

Answer (score 0):

After trying a lot I figured It up by myself.

```
QDate current = ui->dtetimeCurrnt->date();
    //adding 14 days to the current date to get the returning date
    QDate returnDate = current.addDays(14);

    //assigning the returndate to dateedit
    ui->dteditRetrn->setDate(returnDate);
```

Since I couldn't use lineEdit I used a dateEdit.